# Текст посреди 2-х кнопок

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь сделать текст посреди 2-х кнопок, типа такого:

[image: Пример того, что нужно сделать]

А получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопки влево и вправо съезжают непонятно куда. Что можно сделать?

P.S В верстке новичок, ранее только back-end)

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/cars.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
         <div class = "float-right">
             <div class = "card">
                 <div class= "card-body">

                        <div id = "about">
                                <h4 id>Что-нибудь позже тут напишу</h4>
                            </div>

                        <div id = "content">
                                <h4 class = "text-center" id = "car_info">Выберите автомобиль:</h4>
                                <button type="button" id = "next_btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-left"><-</button>
                                <h4 class = "text-center" id = "car_info">Tesla</h4>
                                <button type="button" id = "previus_btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right">-></button>
                        </div>

                            <div id = "end_button">
                                    <button type="button" id = "next" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn btn-block">Далее</button>
                        </div>

                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 3 варианта.

1. Заверни в `row` эти 3 элемента.
2. Заверни в конструкцию `ul li`.
3. Попробуй не использовать тег `h4`

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать возможности CSS3, а именно CSS Flexbox.

Добавляете к родительскому элементу css-свойство `display: flex;`, по дефолту, элементы будут размещены по горизонтали, как вам и нужно.

Подробнее: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Спасибо, тоже очень интересный способ